# How to use promises in asyncData in NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have Users.vue **component** in my **NuxtJS** project. It's look like:

```
<template>
<section>
  <h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user of users" :key="user">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="goTo(user)">User {{ user }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        asyncData() {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve({
                        users : [1,2,3,4,5]
                    })
                }, 3000)
            })
        },
        data() {
            return {
                pageTitle: "Это страница с пользователями"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            goTo(user) {
                return this.$router.push('/users/' + user)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I use **promise** in asyncData(), I have error **[Vue warn]: Property or method "users" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.**

Comment: the `asyncData()` is only available in page components. Get the users data in`asyncData()` of  page component first, and pass it to the components inside of page component

Comment: [Doc](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data)

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how can I pass data from page to component?

Comment: Via props. Or use the `fetch()` hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fetch hook, but on client fetch executed after page is opened.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook

For "Property or method 'users' is not defined" add "default" users to data or use `<li v-if="users" v-for="user of users" :key="user">`

```
<template>
<section>
  <h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user of users" :key="user">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="goTo(user)">User {{ user }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        fetch() {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                      this.users = [1,2,3,4,5];                        
                      resolve();
                }, 3000)
            })
        },
        data() {
            return {
                users: [],
                pageTitle: "Это страница с пользователями"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            goTo(user) {
                return this.$router.push('/users/' + user)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```